# IDQ input parameter file error

Tags: informatica, data-quality

In IDQ infacmd I am trying to execute multiple wf with source input parameter file, The first infacmd gets success but the second infacmd mapping fails because of input parameter is taking the default value not the assigned value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I believe I might know the answer, but indeed - as Jeroen indicated - a better description would help. Do you have the same paramfile for both tasks, or the firsto one creates/modifies the file? Is this a session paramfile or workflow paramfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got resolved  it, I have created a parameter in workflow level and assigned the mapping parameter to wf parameter and called the wf level parameter in the infacmd . It just  done my work.